# Como fazer para traduzir textos longos?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto

Estamos tentando rever o processo de tradução dos textos novos ou alterados que aparecem em Inglês e substituem os nossos. Não há muitas partes do site *ainda por traduzir* e a maior parte do que brota em Inglês é por conta de mudanças no texto original.

Estamos constantemente alterando as mensagens, janelas, etc, etc dos nosso sites e isso se reflete na qualidade do nosso site. Se este é um site para pessoas que falam Português, não faz sentido que vocês tenham que lidar com coisas em outra língua. Vamos discutir nas próximas semanas um meio de impedir essas sobrescritas mas eu gostaria de saber a opinião da Comunidade sobre uma situação específica.

O conteúdo do Help Center *também* é revisado, volta e meia, e isso faz com que a nossa Central de Ajuda herde essas alterações, revertendo para o Inglês. Isso não é ideal. A nossa ajuda deve estar sempre disponível na nossa língua.

Queremos reter essas alterações até que a tradução seja feita e aí gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre 3 possibilidades:

- **Empresa de Tradução**
  Hoje temos uma empresa que faz a tradução (para Português e todas as próximas línguas do SO) dos textos. Não é um processo muito ágil mas também não requer trabalho, exceto de revisão dos textos, como grande parte de vocês já pode observar.
- **Esse quem vos fala**
  Eu posso traduzir os textos. Não sei o quão mais rápido seria em relação à empresa de tradução, mas pelo menos o resultado seria mais alinhado com o contexto do nosso site.
- **Tradução comunitária**
  Questionou-se diversas vezes que nós abríssemos o processo de tradução para a comunidade. Isso é inviável para o site como um todo, mas a Central de Ajuda (ou postagens no blog) é outro esquema. A melhor parte da tradução comunitária é diminuir a influência de uma única ótica sobre o texto, seja de alguém de fora ou alguém de... "cima" -- empresa de tradução ou eu, respectivamente.

Todas as opções tem seus pontos fortes e fracos. Também é possível que a solução seja uma mescla de duas possibilidades (esperar a empresa de tradução e minha revisão, por exemplo), mas algo precisa ser feito.

Nosso ideal é permitir o acesso ao conhecimento de pessoas sem impor uma barreira linguística. Dessa maneira, é melhor ter informações desatualizadas por algum tempo do que um artigo cheirando a novo, mas em outra língua.

O que vocês acham?

---

## Update

Apesar das diversas boas ideias e discussões aqui, eu tenho a impressão de que não expressei direito a minha intenção com esse tópico. Além disso, é fácil perceber que a falta de conhecimento sobre como funcionam as traduções impede que vocês tenham ideias ainda melhores.

Então decidi fazer um apanhado sobre como funcionam as traduções. Se ficar meio complicado de entender, **por favor me avisem**. Quanto mais pessoas entenderem, melhor para a discussão.

### O início

Como vocês devem saber, nós contratamos uma empresa de tradução que passou boa parte do ano passado recebendo um *dump* de strings, ou blocos de texto, e retornando traduções que eram aplicadas no site. Simples assim.

Uma das primeiras coisas que eu fiz foi revisar o resultado no contexto do site e, como era de se esperar, haviam várias coisas quebradas. Principalmente porque este é um site muito difícil de se traduzir. Alguns de vocês sabem disso apenas de participarem no Meta e proporem pequenos ajustes.

Existem 2 lugares diferentes onde as traduções podem ser consertadas. A Central de Ajuda pode ser alterada de dentro da nossa engine, enquanto todo o resto é modificado por um "override system" construído especialmente para as traduções.

### Central de Ajuda

Todo site no SE herda seu conteúdo diretamente da Central de Ajuda do MSE. Inclusive o SOpt. Isso acontece porque queremos manter uma uniformidade na ajuda para usuários de todos os sites. As alterações realizadas no MSE são automaticamente distribuidas e aplicadas em todos os outros os sites.

Algumas páginas, entretanto, precisam ser customizadas para cada site, como o **on-topic** e para isso temos um sistema que sobrescreve as páginas originais apenas para aquele site. A partir daí, alterações no conteúdo original - no MSE - deixam de ter efeito para aquela página.

Todas as páginas do SOpt são do tipo "override", e podem ser alteradas à qualquer momento, com efeito imediato. Por algum motivo técnico isso não estava impedindo que alterações no conteúdo original fossem aplicadas na nossa CA, mas me garantiram que isso foi resolvido. Alvíssaras!

#### Tradução

Os textos em Inglês na CA são enviados para a empresa de tradução e depois aplicados como "override" aqui no SOpt. Nem tudo funciona perfeitamente, como vocês podem ver. Alguns títulos podem ser editados, outros títulos não podem ser editados e estão em Português, outros não podem ser editados e estão em Inglês. Não sei o motivo, mas os devs já estão cientes e espero ter uma resposta (em 6-8 semanas).

Nós podemos nos adiantar à empresa de tradução, traduzindo coisas novas, ou parcialmente novas, sempre que necessário. Isso deveria ser feito aqui no Meta, pelo menos no futuro próximo. O formato para isso ainda pode ser discutido. Por enquanto eu gostaria de saber se a comunidade estava disposta a fazer isso.

A resposta foi, como eu esperava, um estrondoso "sim". Isso **não significa que a empresa de tradução será dispensada**, apenas que podemos nos adiantar a um processo que é lento, sempre que estivermos dispostos.

### Strings menores

**Tudo** que não faz parte da CA é traduzido por mim, nesse sistema bastante intuitivo:
[image: Tela de override]

Que aplica as alterações assim que o site passa por um novo build. Nesse caso, é bem difícil que a comunidade possa ajudar sem que tenhamos que criar um novo conjunto de ferramentas. Por enquanto, o jeito é deixar como está.

Gigantesco update, mas acho que expliquei tudo que podia sobre as traduções. Qualquer dúvida, peçam esclarecimentos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Futuro

Semana passada nós tivemos uma longa reunião sobre como melhorar vários processos em relação aos sites internacionais, entre eles as traduções. Eis um apanhado do que ficou decidido:

1. Melhorias serão feitas naquela tela de tradução de strings, entre elas:

   - Notificação de novas strings
   - Identificação de onde as strings são aplicadas no site (para encontrar mais facilmente os erros)
   - Listagem, em qualquer página, de todas as strings presentes nela (também para encontrar os erros mais facilmente)
   - Mudança no processo de build para dar uma chance de traduzir strings novas **antes** delas irem para o ar
2. A CA não vai mais herdar automaticamente da versão em Inglês
3. Criação de uma ferramenta, provavelmente como as filas atuais, para permitir que a comunidade proponha novas traduções sem depender do Meta. O resultado **nunca** vai pro ar sem aprovação de um CM.

Ainda é importante lembrar que mesmo com tudo isso em prática, nosso site estará sempre quebrado (com strings em Inglês) ou atrasado (com strings em Português que não refletem o original). Isso ainda é um grande problema a ser resolvido, porque envolve várias, grandes, peças diferentes.

Answer (score 20):

Eu diria: **Tradução comunitária**.

Acho que esse método é o melhor para garantir que o conteúdo é atual, correto nos vários dialetos de português que aqui usamos, e gera mais sentido comunitário no sentido do "site é para nós".

Existe um outro aspeto que tem de estar ligado a este, e é talvez mais importante: tem de ser bem claro como se aplica uma tradução. Ou seja: depois da discussão e aceitação de uma versão algúem tem de implementar. Esse passo é hoje meio obscuro. Ás vezes é feito na hora, ás vezes demora meses. Tem de ser claro quem têm acesso a esta ferramenta para sentir-mos que o feedback/discussão produz efeito e sabemos a quem nos dirigir-mos.

Comment: Eu posso aplicar as traduções. Quando elas não ocorrem rapidamente é por um de dois motivos possíveis: 1. Culpa minha (não vi, esqueci, não terminei ainda) ou 2. Não é "traduzível" por algum motivo técnico e aí preciso levar aos devs (6-8 semanas). Artigos da Central de Ajuda **sempre** são traduzíveis, então não há problema. Além disso, a revisão do processo de tradução envolve também tentar agilizá-lo ao máximo.

Comment: Ótimo @Gabe! Pena que demora 6-8 semanas caso seja preciso "intervenção devina". Ok, fica a minha resposta com o voto na alternativa "comunidade". Vamos ver o que outros dizem.

Comment: Acho que comunidade é o caminho. Isso inclui o benefício das _traduções Gabisticas_, somado ao conhecimento da comunidade. Empresa de tradução não funciona bem para português, por falta da cultura sobre o assunto sendo traduzido. Não falo de SOpt apenas. Este é um problema que acontece nos grandes sistemas operacionais, tradução de UI de smartphones, jogos dos grandes players do mercado (que são grandes empresas com equipes competentes, mas não se livram da tradução fora de contexto). Poderia falar mais uma imensidão de coisas, mas acho que a idéia é bem evidente.

Comment: PS: Com o advento dos sites internacionais da SE, acho que o @Gabe pode ser o embaixador da idéia da UI "traduzível" pela comunidade. Este problema vai ser constante em toda a "rede internacional" mesmo, creio que o assunto mereça um tratamento global vindo da SE.

Comment: @bacco Apesar de honrado (:D), nesse caso não estamos falando de tradução da UI. A tradução do SOpt foi feita pela empresa contratada e nós da comunidade consertamos ou nos adiantamos diversas coisas, pelos problemas que você citou. Achou que o post não ficou muito claro... Vou tentar dar uma melhorada mais tarde

Comment: @Gabe eu tinha entendido, só acabei aproveitando o comentário pra estender a idéia. Talvez eu não tenha utilizado o melhor meio, mas na pressa de não perder a ocasião, acabei misturando as 2 coisas. Por UI não entenda a UI dos sites, mas sim uma UI nova para a comunidade traduzir coisas em geral (help/textos da central de ajuda, novas strings da UI do site até, etc).

Comment: @Bacco Ah, sim. Talvez, no futuro... Mas antes teríamos que implementar um modelo de tradução, provavelmente no nosso Meta, que prove que uma tradução comunitária pode dar certo.

Comment: @Gabe Se a ideia é usar o meta, podemos começar com uma pergunta dizendo qual é o texto a ser traduzido (função dele, link e texto completo), e uma única resposta, community wiki, para a tradução. Mas como o Bacco eu gostaria muito de ter uma ferramenta mais especializada para isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto sua idéia é exatamente a que eu tive mas, como eu disse, minha intenção agora é saber se a comunidade tem interesse em traduzir esses textos

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou talvez múltiplas respostas ineditáveis em que a mais votada seja a aplicada na prática. Assim impede de uma pessoa só mudar a tradução. (Mas por outro lado, deixa uma mudança muito difícil depois de muitos votos)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Desse jeito, cada um teria de fazer uma tradução do zero. Acho muito trabalhoso e pouco comunitário...

Comment: @bfavaretto Oops, estava com pequenas frases na cabeça. Com artigos completos, é melhor uma postagem só mesmo.

Comment: @Gabe estive a dar mais uma olhada aqui no meta e a perguntas que demoraram a traduzir. Algumas demoraram meses, nõ somente 6-8 semanas, e mesmo seria desejável evitar. Como seria possivel ser a comunidade a aplicar essas mudanças? Acho que isso seria uma boa discussão, não vejo que seja melhor depender de 1 pessoa em vez de escrever algumas linhas de código que dão essa ferramenta para a comunidade.

Comment: @sergio em nenhum site da rede a comunidade inteira tem poder sobre o conteúdo da Central de Ajuda. Mesmo os moderadores tem poder apenas para editar diretamente o on-topic (e ainda assim, os CMs são alertados das mudanças). Como eu disse, nós queremos rever e atualizar todo o processo, isso potencialmente incluiria a criação de ferramentas que garantissem uma aplicação mais rápida do texto traduzido.

Comment: @Gabe "rever e atualizar todo o processo" soa excelente. O SOpt pode ser um bom local para testar uma tal nova ferramenta onde a comunidade tem poder sobre revisão/tradução até de conteudos estruturais. Até porque o plano da SE é expandir para outras linguas.

Comment: Alterações nas ferramentas existentes e/ou criação de novas me parece indispensável. Eu acho que precisa haver um compromisso desse tipo da parte da SE *antes* de dispensar a empresa de tradução e entregar a tarefa para a comunidade. @Gabe

Comment: Concordo plenamente. A comunidade é mais do que capaz de lidar com essas traduções. Seria interessante a criação de uma nova ferramenta parecida com o que já existe para edições de posts, com aprovação por outros usuários. Talvez a única diferença nesse caso é que pode haver uma aprovação final pelo representante da comunidade, @Gabe, para validar se não houver "aprovação automática" por parte dos usuários que analisam a fila de edições.

Comment: Neste caso acho que não deve ter fila de análise, e sim somente votos "voluntários". E essa parte não pode ser _gamificada_ também, senão vira bagunça. Mereceria uma ferramenta mais apropriada, em que trabalhássemos na "candidate", onde alterações precisassem de aprovação incondicional de N pessoas, e mesmo assim, ficasse a cargo da moderação liberar pra visualização geral. Nós não editariamos a versão "live" nunca, sempre a próxima. Assim dá pra ver o que já foi sendo aprovado até a versão final tomar forma, e só depois substituir a velha. Não basta reciclar as ferramentas de Q&A.

Answer (score 6):

Sobre as três opções (tradutores, você e a comunidade), hoje nós temos as três ao mesmo tempo. A empresa de tradução é uma das partes mais lentas do processo todo, e com o fim dos textos longos nunca traduzidos ela não precisa mais de uma presença constante no site. Pode ficar para coisas mais esporádicas. Realmente fica mais complicado contar com ela para atualizações como as da Central de ajuda, onde se espera mais agilidade.

Sobramos a comunidade e a Stack Exchange. A comunidade vem se oferecendo para ajudar com tradução desde antes que o site abrisse, e vem participando pelo meta. Os votos nas respostas aqui indicam que continuamos dispostos a participar. Está mesmo na hora de incluir a comunidade formalmente no processo. Criar algum tipo de protocolo no meta já seria uma melhora, mas não vejo como escapar de uma ferramenta adequada para cuidar de todos os processos envolvidos. O workflow de hoje exige bastante trabalho manual para todos, e poderia ser bem mais ágil. Vocês estão criando mais dois sites que também se beneficiariam da nova ferramenta – com sorte, mais cedo que a gente. Seria interessante traçar um plano de médio prazo nesse sentido, em conjunto com a comunidade.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que temos que separar entre texto longo e texto curto, e entre texto que precisa da chancela da gerencia e texto comum e corrente.

## Texto longo x Texto curto

Não sei dizer se existe algum texto longo que não precise do carimbo dos *managers*. Normalmente, é o tipo de texto que precisa sim de ir para a empresa de tradução. Pode haver um *crowdsourcing* mas creio que depende da definição de um e outro e de seu *status* para aprovação.

## Texto da companhia x Texto comum

Aqui acho que o *crowdsourcing* pode funcionar muito bem para os textos que **não precisam que um *manager* da companhia tenha que dizer `"ok, estamos de acordo"`**.

Pôxa, a gente tá aqui, dia sim, dia não, exercitando nosso direito de wiki editores, ajustando formatação e ortografia pra cima e pra baixo. De onde surgiu a noção de que não temos interesse em ajudar na edição de umas meras *strings* no banco de dados?

## Idéia

Espera aí, o site já tem uma ferramenta de *crowdsourcing* para revisão editorial. Fica aqui encima no [*MultiCollider SuperDropdown™*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420/185667), ítem [<kbd>análise</kbd>](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/review).

Algo parecido com a edição ninja de tags:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E que isso fosse parar numa fila de análise "Localização". Somente  10k+ (ou valores beta) poderiam propor alterações e precisaria da aprovação de uns 5 outros 10k+, p.ex. E com penalidades severas para o mau uso da ferramenta.

Comment: hmm, tudo bem o `análise` não é supermulticollider *per se*, mas se precisar [a gente muda](http://stackapps.com/questions/4921/turbocharged-help-menu)!

Comment: Como eu disse, é uma discussão que vamos ter esta semana aqui na SE, então minha previsão pode estar errada, mas não acredito que qualquer texto, longo ou curto, poderá ser editado e aprovado sem passar pela gerência. Não significa que não possa haver uma filha no futuro, mas que ela nunca aplicaria as traduções em produção sem nosso crivo.

Comment: @Gabe Isso é mais um motivo para que se implemente algum tipo de ferramenta de tradução. Se o *staff* altera um texto escrito/traduzido/revisado pela comunidade antes de colocar no ar, essa alteração precisa ficar registrada em histórico (assim como qualquer outra). Vocês precisam saber onde a comunidade mexe, e a comunidade precisa saber o que vocês não aprovam ou quiseram melhorar.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que seria legal pegar cada texto longo e colocar como pergunta aqui no Meta, com uma tag do tipo [pedido-de-tradução](/questions/tagged/pedido-de-tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Daí cada membro a seu tempo pode responder com a tradução, e a gente escolhe as mais adequadas por votação.

Comment: Sim, mas tem 2 gargalos aí (assumindo que vão alterar o sistema para deixar de sobrescrever os conteúdos com novas versões em EN). A cada alteração do original, alguém (Gabe?) precisa ser notificado, e esse alguém precisa postar o texto no meta para tradução. Após o fim da tradução (como decidir quando está "pronto"?), alguém (Gabe?) precisa atualizar manualmente a central de ajuda. Ou seja: teremos mais trabalho que hoje, o processo seria mais complexo do que existe hoje, com menos ajuda (sai a empresa de tradução) e mais dependência do Gabe. Como isso pode ser mais ágil que o que já temos?